# C++ semantic type wrapping

Tags: c++, overloading

I have a data type for example `class Vector3`. Now I need to create several classes with same interface as `Vector3`, but with higher level semantic (for example: `Position`, `Velocity`). Using `typedef` is not enough, because I need these types to be distinct so that they can be used for overloading. In C++0x I could probably use constructor inheritance:

```
struct Position: public Vector3 {
    using Vector3::Vector3;
};
```

Could there be any problems with this? Is there any better way to do it? Is it possible to do it without using C++0x features and not having to explicitly write all `Vector3` constructors?

Comment: The problem with this is that positions are implicitly convertible to vectors (and that technically speaking, Vector must now have a virtual destructor in order to be used safely)

Comment: @jalf: Is the virtual destructor really needed even when the derived class does not add any data or methods?

Comment: jalf: I discuss the topic of conversions in my answer

Comment: It is undefined behavior if you delete the derived object through a pointer to the base object and the base destructor is not virtual, regardless of whether the derived type added anything or not.

Comment: yes, according to the standard. In practice, it'll typically work without the virtual dtor, but you have no guarantee of it (and in particular, compilers often exploit some kinds of undefined behavior during optimization. They assume that it never occurs, and so if it does, all sorts of weird behavior may result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using a tag struct

```
struct tagPosition {};
struct tagDirection {};
struct tagGeneric {};

namespace detail
{
    template <typename Tag=tagGeneric>
        class Vector3
    {
        // business as usual
    };
}

typedef detail::Vector3<tagPosition>  Position;
typedef detail::Vector3<tagDirection> Direction;
typedef detail::Vector3<tagGeneric>   Vector3;
```

For bonus points, have conversion operators/constructors:

```
    template <typename Tag=tagGeneric>
        class Vector3
    {
        template <typename OtherTag>
            explicit Vector3(const Vector3<OtherTag>& rhs) { /* ... */ }

//      template <typename OtherTag>
//            operator Vector3<OtherTag>() const { return /* ... */ }
    };
```

If you like to live dangerously you can drop the `explicit` keyword, or enable the implicit conversion operator. This would have the 'benefit' of being able to enable ***promiscuous*** operator resolutions like so:

```
 Position pos;
 Direction dir;
 Generic gen;

 dir = gen + pos; // you see why I call it 'promiscuous'?
```

I'd recommend (instead) to define explicit operators for cases like this (free functions:)

```
 Position operator+(const Position& v, const Translation& d) { /* .... */ }
```

That way your class model reflects the semantics of your classes.

[C++0x would possibly contain things to enable explicit conversion operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#Explicit_conversion_operators), IIRC:

> In the case of converting constructors, you can disable implicit conversions by declaring the constructor as explicit The [N1592 proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1592.pdf) stretches the semantics of this keyword to all conversion operators. A conversion operator declared explicit will not perform an implicit conversion. Instead, the programmer will have to call it explicitly

Comment: If you want to be mathematically correct, you should only allow the following: Position + Vector = Position; Position - Position = Vector; Direction == Vector; Direction * Speed = Velocity (Speed is a _scalar_ in units 1/time!). Positions aren't strictly vectors, but points in an affine space. Your "Velocity * Direction" is confusing -  both are vectors, what does their product mean?

Comment: @Kerrek: I had no such assumptions, and they are not relevant. The semantics in my example need not be correct nor incorrect. _(besides, how can you first say my example is wrong, and only after that ask me what the things mean? Perhaps Direction is a Unity Vector by definition. Note that the sample doesn't specify how Direction might **derive** from Vector3. Just imagine that it has the proper invariants for the sake of the example_). -- just saying!

Comment: @sehe: You made `Velocity` a vector. Now what could Velocity times Direction possibly mean? Just curious!

Comment: @Kerrek: yeah, braindamage there. **Edit** I just copied that blindly from the question -- as it turns out :)

Comment: @sehe: I can see how a dedicated `Direction` class of unit vectors could be conceived (all operations normalize?)... I wonder if that'd be useful. I guess it could be implemented with only _two_ scalar data members (at least up to orientation).

Comment: @Kerrek: you're getting way off-topic. I tried to reduce the confusion in my sample, FWIW. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

When I've needed distinct-but-similar types I've generally used a dummy template parameter, like (off the cuff, untouched by compiler's dirty hands)

```
template< class UniqueId >
struct Blah {};

typedef Blah< struct AlphaId > Alpha;
typedef Blah< struct BetaId > Beta;
```

This may or may not be what you need.

Cheers &  hth.,